# Why simulator getting crash on Device change from simulator in Xcode 5?

Tags: xcode, xcode5

When i run simulator in my xcode 5 and later on if i try to change simulator Device from under menu 'hardware' of simulator it getting crash. which is something unlikely to xcode previous versions. Is it my xcode copy specific bug or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Instead of changing the device in the iOS simulator, change to the device of your preference in XCode. Notice your project name in the top left hand corner next to build and run button and stop button. To the right of that is a drop down for different device names. Pick the one that you'd like to simulate. Then build and run in iOS simulator.